# Javascript - Update object in array by id and move it to the first index

Tags: javascript, performance, ecmascript-6

I have this array:

```
const chats = [
   { id: "chat-1", msg: { text: "World", date: (a date) } },
   { id: "chat-2", msg: { text: "Hello", date: (a date) } },
];
```

After receiving updates from my database, I receive this object:

```
  // The second chat with update data
  { id: "chat-2", msg: { text: "Bye", date: (a date) } },
```

How can I (using ES6) replace the chat object from the original chats array and move it to the first index?

For now, I am doing this, but I am looking for a fastest way (smaller O)

```
// Get the modified chat
const modifiedChat = response.data;

// Search the modified chat in the chats array by id
const chatIndex = chats.findIndex(
    (chat) => chat.id === modifiedChat.id
);

 // Finally, using spread syntax, add the updated chat to the head of our current chats array
 chats = [
    modifiedChat,
    ...chats.slice(0, chatIndex),
    ...chats.slice(chatIndex + 1),
 ];
```

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do it that isn't O(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following,

```js
const chats = [
   { id: "chat-1", msg: { text: "World", date: '' } },
   { id: "chat-2", msg: { text: "Hello", date: '' } },
];

const modifiedChat = { id: "chat-2", msg: { text: "Bye", date: '' } };

const newChats = [modifiedChat, ...chats.filter(item => item.id !== modifiedChat.id)];

console.log(newChats);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar to how [LRU cache](https://www.interviewcake.com/concept/java/lru-cache) works. You can now access every chat in O(1)